# Choice sharePoint field which allow multiple selections and allow fill in. How to implement it inside Canvas Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

We have a SharePoint column named "Types" of type Choice which allow multiple selections and allow Fill-in, as follow: -

[image]

so how I can implement this field inside our canvas form, where we will have to deal with these 3 scenarios:-

1. ONLY select single/multiple choice without entering custom value.
2. BOTH select single/multiple choice/s + enter a custom value
3. ONLY enter a custom value

This should work inside the Add ,Edit & View built-in Power Apps forms...Here is the UI which i currently have >> to select available option/s and/or enter custom value:-

[image]

any advice how to implement the logic for this field?

Thanks in advance for any help